# 'Delete' function works and does not work with ko.observableArray()

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am new to Knockout and still learn it.
  I have a simple page so users can add and delete items.  The 'delete' function (named 'deleteItem') works with Version 1 codes, but not with Version 2 codes. Please help me to know the reason behind. Thanks in advance.

By the way, the codes for Version 2 come from Note 7 near the bottom at the link http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_5_postprocessing_or_animating_the_generated_dom_elements

The codes for Version 1 come from Example 2 at that same link.

**Details of my codes:**

The difference between the 2 versions is:

In Version 1, property 'myItems' is an array of objects that have 'name' property.
In Version 2, property 'myItems' is an array of elements that does not have any property. Those array elements are just literal strings.

**Version 1** codes: the "Delete" function (named 'deleteItem') is working

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: myItems}">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span> <a href="#"  data-bind="click : $parent.deleteItem" 

>Delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
</div

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function ViewModel() {
             var self = this;

            self.myItems = ko.observableArray([{ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }, { name: 'C' } ]);  /*********/
            self.addItem = function () { self.myItems.push({ name: 'New item at ' + new Date() }); }         


            self.deleteItem = function () {
                self.myItems.remove(this);
            };
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

    });

</script>
```

**Version 2**:  the "Delete" function (named 'deleteItem') is not working

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: myItems">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span> <a href="#"  data-bind="click : $parent.deleteItem" 

>Delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.myItems = ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']);  /*********/
            self.addItem = function () { self.myItems.push('item added at ' + new Date()); };

            self.deleteItem = function () {
                self.myItems.remove(this);
            };
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect the `this` to be the current model in a `click` handler.

Instead of the `this` you should use the fist parameter of the handler which is guaranteed to be the current model:

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html):

> When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model value as the first parameter.

So you need to rewrite your `deleteItem` to:

```
self.deleteItem = function (item) {
    self.myItems.remove(item);
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8MR4w/2/)

Note it will work in both of your samples.

Comment: nemesv, thank you for your kind explanation and updated solution for version 2 codes. I've given you an up-vote.

Comment: In the fiddle, if you add 5 new items and select the Remove from the 2nd item that was newly added, it would remove all the elements from 2nd to the 5th elements that were newly added.

Comment: @bhagyas yeah, because the items are strings and if you add them fast you will adding the same string again and again so the remove will be confused. If you are using proper object instead of strings (or unique strings) it is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8MR4w/2/